# Android Save Textview with transparent background

Tags: android, android-canvas, textview, android-bitmap

I'm trying to render text by creating a canvas for bitmap and than textview is drawn on canvas and than it is saved as PNG image. I have 3 channels in it not having 4th channel alpha in it. Now how can i add alpha to bitmap.

```
Bitmap testB;
strLogoImagePath = "storage/sdcard0/as.png";

testB = Bitmap.createBitmap(objTextView.getWidth(), objTextView.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

Canvas c = new Canvas(testB);

objTextView.layout(0, 0, objTextView.getWidth(), objTextView.getHeight());

objTextView.draw(c);


objTextView.setLayoutParams(rlLayoutParamsCanvas); 
FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(strLogoImagePath); 
testB.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
testB.recycle();
stream.close();
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? I didn't understand if you want to set the background of a `TextView` to `transparent`, or if you want to set the alpha of an `ImageView`, or if you want to set the alpha of a bitmap (the last isn't a question about Android).

Comment: @Akagami: I want to convert textview to image file, that image file have no alpha transparency, so i want to add alpha to bitmap because that bitmap hold textview and save that textview as image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding alpha to `Bitmap` is doable using [BitmapDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html)

Keep your method and just :

- Create a `BitmapDrawable` from the beginning or use this constructor `BitmapDrawable(Bitmap bitmap)` to load your existing Bitmap.
- Then use the `BitmapDrawable.setAlpha(int alpha)`.

I hope it will resolve your alpha problem.